# Name mysql table columns using php POST variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an web application where the user fills an html form and the information captured is used to create a table with corresponding columns. However, mysql returns an error where the POST variable is used to name the columns. Here is a sample of the code:

```
$questionnaire = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['questionnaire']));
$question = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['question']));
$answer1 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['answer1']));
$answer2 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['answer2']));

mysql_query = "CREATE TABLE $questionnaire
               (id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                question varchar(200),
                '$answer1' varchar(200),
                '$answer2' varchar(200) )";
```

How do I make the value in `$answer1` be used to give a column its name?

Answer (score 0):

use `BACKTICK` not `SINGLE QUOTES` as column names are identifiers,

```
mysql_query = "CREATE TABLE $questionnaire
               (id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                question varchar(200),
                `$answer1` varchar(200),
                `$answer2` varchar(200) )";
```

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: i tried the backticks and it gives me a new error: Incorrect column name ''

Comment: what are the values you passed on the variables?

Comment: a person's name. its a questionnaire and the answers are used to name the columns

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in parentheses (`'`). If you escape column names, you will need to use backticks.

However, you should reconsider your table layout. If you have to generate tables and/or columns on the fly, there is most certainly something wrong with your design.

Comment: the number of columns is fixed but the names vary from table to table. its a questionnaire so i thought of allocating a table to each question and its answers.

Answer (score 0):

change this `AUTO INCREMENT` to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp